# Do I have to attribute licenses of all the libraries of the same project?

Tags: license-notice, attribution, android, maven

Let's say I use [Jersey Inject](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/project), [Jersey Container Jetty HTTP](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-jetty-http), [Jersey Container Servlet Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core) for the backend of my Android App. In the "Open Source Libraries" section, do I have to mention them all seperately with their own license? Or can I just say "Jersey" and show the [License](https://jersey.github.io/license.html#/epl)?

Answer (score 1):

You should attribute every *project* individually. But here a project seems to produce multiple *artefacts*. You don't have to lists all the JARs.